# Making a " ▶ " to appear before a link when hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, character, special-characters

Heres my [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kytjsdbb/3/)

How do I make a special character like this "▶" to appear before the links when I hover over them, like a selection arrow and is it possible to use a external image instead?

How can this be done in `css` or `javascript` ?

```css
#wrapper {width:400px;font-family:questrial;clear:both;}
#first {width:130px;float:left;}

#wrapper a:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 15px #E81029 inset, 0px -15px #E81029 inset;
    background:#e5122e;
    color:#f6f6f6;
    padding:2px;
    transition-duration:0s;
    padding-left:4px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }
    
.category2 {width:430px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:40px;background:white;
box-shadow:0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15)}

.desc3 {color:#666666;font-family:questrial;font-size:9px;width:350px;text-align:left;}
```

```html
<div class="category2" style="line-height:150%;"><center>
        <div class="desc3">
<div id="wrapper">
    
<div id="first">
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
</div>

    
<div id="third">
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>  
<br><a href="/">Text is here</a>   
</div>
    
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, you can find answer here : http://fontello.com/

Comment: You can probably write some nice css by combining :hover with ::before.

Comment: @Gregorie Why? Seriously, Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a bit of jerk, which can be avoided using `visibility`.

```css
a:hover:before {
  content: '▶';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me</a>
```

Avoiding the jerking bit using `visibility`:

```css
a:before {
  content: '▶';
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me</a>
```

For the same thing with image, you can use `url()`:

```css
a:before {
  content: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/delete_16x16.gif");
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me</a>
```

Final Answer for OP without affecting the `<a>`:

```css
a, span:before {
  color: #00f;
}

span:before {
  content: '▶';
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

span:hover:before {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="#">Hover Me</a></span>
```

Comment: I don't think you would need the content attribute in both rules, only in the:before rule.

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl Yeah, sorry, forgot to remove it.

Comment: @praveen kumar I need the character to be outside, before the red hover colour.

Comment: @Zack Add a wrapping tag like `<span>` before the `<a>` and give the styles for `<span>`. You didn't mention this!

Comment: @Zack Do you want me to update the answer or is it just okay?

Comment: ha, sorry i forgot to mention this. It is better for others if you update the answer.

Comment: @Zack Updated with `<span>` code. Check it out please. `:)`

Comment: @Zack Also the link doesn't jerk when you hover over it. If you want, I can make the colour also to display the same.

Comment: @Zack Thank you so much. `:)`

Answer (score 7):

You can:

```
#wrapper a:hover:before { content: '▶'; }
```

or for an image:

```
#wrapper a:hover:before { content: url(http://xxx); }
```

Comment: I need the character to be outside, before the red hover colour.

Comment: i need the link in the same position and the '▶' appear before it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar shows you how to do that with `visibility/display`

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use css:

```
a:before{
  content: '▶';
}
```

But in practice, I have met a lot of icons that does not exist in unicode so for that I recommend use http://fontello.com/ you can choose many icon and use it like font-family: "fontello"

Comment: This solution does not answer the question. The icon should appear when hovering only.

Comment: And with a:hover:before{ effects... } ?

Comment: .twitter:hover:after{ content: '\e802'; color: red; ... } With fontello it's more simply modify hover effects. And also its possible to chage font-size, what is important for responsive

Comment: I still don't really understand what you mean. Your solution does not answer the question. If you want to answer the question with a product or service in mind, please explain in the answer how that product/service would help, instead of implying the usage in comments.